# Probability of getting n amount of each number from 1-6 after 6n rolls of a dice

Tags: probability, dice

I managed to figure this out for n = 1.

$ \frac{6}{6} \times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{6} \times \frac{3}{6} \times \frac{2}{6} \times \frac{1}{6} $

I thought it would work by putting this to the power of n for all n.

But I can't manage to figure it out for n = 2, more importantly for all n.

I saw solutions online using matrices, however I have no experience with matrices yet so I was wondering if this was possible without it.

Thanks in advance for answers. Also, I know what the answers should be since I ran a computer simulation with pseudo-random numbers, and I'm definitely not getting the right answer.

Comment: Why do you think the probability would change if $n$ changes?

Comment: There is a more specific condition involved when n increases, so the probability must change. I also know from running my computer simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=2$ the number possible results from twelve rolls is $6^{12}$.

If out of $12$ you want two rolls to be equal to $1$, two of the rest to be equal to $2$ etc the number of successful rolls is $$\binom {12}2\binom {10}2\binom 82\binom 62 \binom 42 \binom 22$$

Note that for six rolls you had $$\binom 61\binom 51\binom 41\binom 31\binom  21\binom 11$$ out of $6^6$ possibilities in total.

I am sure you can generalise (and maybe simplify) from that.

Comment: I should add for later viewers that this simplifies to $\cfrac {(6n)!}{(n!)^6}$ which is a multinomial form. Out of $6^{6n}$ possibilities, of course.